# Subclipse with Eclipse x64

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, windows-7-x64

I've just bought a new computer x64 and intalled windows 7 and Eclipse Helios x64. When I tried to install subclipse it didn't work... after a few times trying to install it and getting stuck when eclipse was trying to check the dependences, I did get to install it but it simply didn't work.

When I chenged the perspective to SVN Repository I got an error. Anyway, I downloaded Eclipse Helios x86 and also got stuck on the dependeces checking part. But after a while trying it was installed and now it works.

But the thing is that I want to install eclipse helios x64 since I have a x64 computer.

Did anybody have the same or a similar problem? How did you solve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick to JavaHL way of accessing the repository, you can also install the 64 bits version of JavaHL.

Referenced [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL)  - look at the paragraph saying `Windows 64-bit`.  It will redirect you to [slik subversion client](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download)

You can install the whole client (I could not install only javahl with the custom install)

To make sure it is taken into account, edit your eclipse.ini file and, after the `-vmargs` line, add `-Djava.library.path=C:\programs\slik` (or if you already have an item for the jni path, add your own path).

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Eclipse64 with a working SVN plugin.

But I changed the SVN Client interface from "Java HAL" to "**SVNKit**" which works much better. I installed this module via Yoxos and then switched in the preferences Team > SVN > SVN interface to SVNKit.

Comment: using SVNKit works because this way you use a pure Java implementation of SVN, which usually is OK, but not quite as up to date as the native SVN version.
It is also a bit slower than the native SVN implementation with big merges.
Both version worked fine for me, but I have the feeling the native version was a bit more robust when operating with many files.